# Detect if element has a background specified?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to determine if an element has a background explicitly set. I figured I could just check to see if `.css('background')`* was set, however, it's inconsistent between browsers. For example, chrome shows an element without a background set as

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
background-image: none
```

whereas IE8 shows

```
background: undefined
background-color: transparent
background-image: none
```

(test case [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WG9MC/3/))

*(shorthand properties of CSS aren't supported for getting rendered styles in jQuery)

Short of handling each separate case is there a better way to detect this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### temporary element approach

It's not ideal, but you could create a temporary element when your js initiates, insert it somewhere hidden in the document *(because if you don't you get empty styles for webkit browsers)* and then read the default background style set for that element. This would give you your baseline values. Then when you compare against your real element, if they differ you know that the background has been set. Obviously the downside to this method is it can not detect if you specifically set the background to the baseline state.

```
var baseline = $('<div />').hide().appendTo('body').css('background');

var isBackgroundSet = ( element.css('background') != baseline );
```

If you wanted to avoid possible global styles on elements, that would break the system i.e:

```
div { background: red; }
```

... you could use the following instead, but I doubt if it would work so well with older browsers:

```
var baseline = $('<fake />').hide().appendTo('body').css('background');
```

#### background

I spent some time with a similar issue - attempting to get the original width value from an element when set to a percentage. Which was much trickier than I had assumed, in the end I used a similar temporary element solution. I also expected, as Rene Koch does above, that the `getComputedStyle` method would work... really annoyingly it doesn't. Trying to detect the difference between the source CSS world and the runtime CSS world is a difficult thing.

Comment: +1 It's not ideal but it's certainly better than checking each case. jQuery internally does `getComputedStyle` so it returns the exact same thing.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus Yeah, it's rather annoying that so much of the browser gets in the way when reading css information. I can understand why, but I really wish that there were more powerful hooks that could tie in to the css parsing layer.. even when accessing `.styleSheets` and rulesets you still get controlled and sanitised css objects. If you could hook into the parsing layer you could implement bespoke css properties and read directly what was specified in the original source - rather than what the browser states that it was :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
function isBGDefined(ele){
    var img = $(ele).css('backgroundImage'),
        col = $(ele).css('backgroundColor');

    return img != 'none' || (col != 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' && col != 'transparent');
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dH6zZ/1/)

I didn't bother to test against the `background` property because in the end, it will change the computed styles of either `backgroundImage` and/or `backgroundColor`.

Here's the code run against your test case (with another added): http://jsfiddle.net/WG9MC/4/

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to avoid explicitly checking each possible value.

Comment: Yeah, I don't blame you. This wouldn't be very maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

this article explains how: 
http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/

```
function getStyle(oElm, strCssRule){
    var strValue = "";
    if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){
        strValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(oElm, "").getPropertyValue(strCssRule);
    }
    else if(oElm.currentStyle){
        strCssRule = strCssRule.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function (strMatch, p1){
            return p1.toUpperCase();
        });
        strValue = oElm.currentStyle[strCssRule];
    }
    return strValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the article but's it not what I'm looking for. The background property is still inconsistently returned.

Answer (score 0):

Using the approach suggested by @pebbl I wrote a small jQuery function, `hasBack()`, to determine if an element has its background set.

```
$.fn.hasBack = function()
{
    var me = $.fn.hasBack;
    if(!me.cache)
    {
        // get the background color and image transparent/none values
        // create a temporary element
        var $tmpElem = $('<div />').hide().appendTo('body');
        $.fn.hasBack.cache = {
            color: $tmpElem.css('background-color'),
            image: $tmpElem.css('background-image')
        };
        $tmpElem.remove();
    }
    var elem = this.eq(0);
    return !(elem.css('background-color') === me.cache.color && elem.css('background-image') === me.cache.image);
}
```

This was tested in Chrome v22, Firefox v15, Opera 12.1, IE9, IE9 set to browser modes 9 compat, 9, 8, 7 and quirks mode.

Test case [here](http://jsfiddle.net/emosaurusrex/DACwz/).